# How do libraries to provide users a bindData function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I need to copy the behaviour of, for example, the "create" function of Axios:

```
// fileOne.js
import axios from 'axios';


const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api'
});
```

Then to use that baseURL in another file, with another function like this:

```
// fileTwo.js
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('/user/12345'); // https://some-domain.com/api/user/12345
```

Getting this as result:
**https://some-domain.com/api/user/12345**

How does Axios to bind the baseURL data in his library.

I'm looking that library but i don't understand how they do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the official documentation [Config Defaults](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) section.

> You can specify config defaults that will be applied to every request.

**Global axios defaults**

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://some-domain.com/api';

// use it later
axios.get('/user/12345')
```

**Custom instance defaults**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api'
});

// use it later
instance.get('/user/12345')
```

Source code explanation of *axios v1.2.1*

The `Axios` class has a [`defaults`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.2.1/lib/core/Axios.js#L23)
property, axios will [merge config](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.2.1/lib/core/Axios.js#L48) when dispatch a request. The `axios` package will call [createInstance](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.2.1/lib/axios.js#L45) to create an `axios` instance of the `Axios` class with built-in [default config](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.2.1/lib/defaults/index.js#L40).

There is a [buildFullPath](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.2.1/lib/core/buildFullPath.js#L16) function to build the full request URL use `baseURL` and `requestedURL`(Absolute or relative URL to combine, in your case, it's `/user/12345`)